# Unable to reference MovieClip inside Button AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, movieclip

I have this annoying issue that I hope someone might be able to help me with.

I have a mute button that I created and I have another movieclip inside of that button. All I want it to do is when I toggle the mute the movieclip inside will go to the according frame.

However, every time I try to call the movieclip inside of the button, this error comes up:

> Access of possibly undefined property mcMuteToggle through a reference with static type flash.display:SimpleButton.

The instance name for the movieclip within is "mcMuteToggle".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not make movieClips that act like buttons?? Since I dont think actual `button` (simpleButton) types can deal with sub-MovieClips (especially if they too have code). Even if possible don't do it, I can predict a mess whereby `Button` does things it shouldn't do depending on what code you have in those MClips.

Try an alternate button method, just for a test... You didnt show any test code to work with so I will make assumptions..

1) Make a shape (rectangle?) and convert to MovieClip (or if all coded, then `addchild` shape to new MovieClip). Let's assume you called it **mc_testBtn**.

2) Make that MC clickable by coding `mc_testBtn.buttonMode = true;`

3) Add your **mcMuteToggle** inside the **mc_testBtn** 
(or by code: `mc_testBtn.addChild(mcMuteToggle);`

Now you can try something like..

```
mc_testBtn.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, toggle_Mute );

function toggle_Mute (evt:MouseEvent) : void
{
    if ( whatever condition )
    {
        mc_testBtn.mcMuteToggle.gotoAndStop(2); //go frame 2
    }
    else
    {
        mc_testBtn.mcMuteToggle.gotoAndStop(1); //go frame 1
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have thought of this before...thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to strict mode. You can either disable it in the ActionScript settings dialog, access it with a different syntax `myButton['mcMuteToggle']`, or make a class for the symbol that includes a property `mcMuteToggle`.

You can also check to make sure the symbol is actually on the stage and that clip is actually in the button:

```
if('myButton' in root) { 
    // ...
}

if('mcMuteToggle' in myButton) { 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm not quite sure what you mean but I did try creating a class for but it didn't work unfortunately. Sorry, not really experienced in flash.

Answer (score 0):

i think u just overwrite that codes. You u can use something like this:

```
 var soundOpen:Boolean = true;
    var mySound:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("Whatever your sound is"));
    var mySc:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
    var mySt:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
    mySc = mySound.play();

    mcMuteToggle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, muteOpenSound);

    function muteOpenSound(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if(soundOpen == true)
        {
            mcMuteToggle.gotoAndStop(2);
/*on frame 2 u need to hold ur soundClose buton so ppl can see :)*/
            soundOpen = false;
            mySt.volume = 0;
            mySc.soundTransfrom = st;
        }
        else
        {
            mcMuteToggle.gotoAndStop(1);
            soundOpen = true;
            mySt.volume = 1;
            mySc.soundTransfrom = st;
        }
    }
```

This is working for me everytime. Hope u can use it well ;)

Comment: yeah that's exactly what i did but I used sound mixer. But the issue is not with the function of the button itself, but rather the visual side of it...not sure if i'm making sense haha

Comment: Codes should be like this and inside your mcMuteToggle on frame 1 Open sound graphics, on frame 2 close sound graphics. if u set your mcMuteToggle button/MovieClip like this this will work anyway :)

Comment: my code is as such: `btn_Mute.mcMuteToggle.gotoAndStop(1);` but the it keeps giving me the error

Comment: If its okey for you can u please type all your code here. I might be help like this cause normally `btn_Mute.mcMuteToggle.gotoAndStop(1);` should work.

Comment: And also are you sure u have an mc named `btn_Mute` , inside that u have `mcMuteToggle` and  `mcMuteToggle` this button got frame1 and frame2 ? Is there any code inside this `mcMuteToggle` ?

Comment: Well i saw u got your answer its nice then :)

Comment: Thanks for your replies though, they are greatly appreciated. To answer your question, what you explained about the button and movieclip is spot on and there is no code inside `mcMuteToggle`